# AngularJS Filter by ID

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have the following Json_encode FRom PHP Response...

```
[
{"ID":"149","IDusr":"4","aut_more_info":"good","doc_name":"img1838142879.jpeg","doc_type":"jpg"},{"ID":"149","IDusr":"4","aut_more_info":"good","img5733250433.jpeg","doc_type":"jpg"},{"ID":"149","IDusr":"4","aut_more_info":"good","doc_name":"img1230306801.jpg_doc","doc_type":"jpg"}
]
```

And I have tried the https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter Plugin. Here is my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in Detail | groupBy: 'ID'">
        <div ng-repeat="aut in value">

            <div class="item item-avatar bar bar-calm">
                <h2>{{aut.name}} {{aut.model}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="../www/img/icon/{{aut.doc_name}}">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

AS you see from the Array, I have the same ID but the doc_name is different, Means I want to show the ID once but the three Images should be shown as well. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: for id use `{{key}}` before n-repeat on value.

Comment: will you please create a plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: There's a problem in your JSON. `"aut_more_info":"good","img5733250433.jpeg",` should have `doc_name` before the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your JSON whereby you are missing a property name.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/weoqMtNdq1kqhi6w8FhV?p=preview).

```
angular.module('foo', ['angular.filter'])

.controller('bar', ['$scope', function($scope){


  $scope.Detail = [
    {
      "ID"            : "149",
      "IDusr"         : "4",
      "aut_more_info" : "good",
      "doc_name"      : "img1838142879.jpeg",
      "doc_type"      : "jpg"
    },
    {
      "ID"            :"149",
      "IDusr"         :"4",
      "aut_more_info" :"good",

      // you were missing the property name 'doc_name' here...
      "doc_name"      :"img5733250433.jpeg",
      "doc_type"      :"jpg"

    },
    {
      "ID"            :"149",
      "IDusr"         :"4",
      "aut_more_info" :"good",
      "doc_name"      :"img1230306801.jpg_doc",
      "doc_type"      :"jpg"
    }
  ];

}]);
```

Also you seem to be trying to render values for properties that don't exist in your JSON data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body ng-app="foo">



    <div ng-controller="bar">

      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in Detail | groupBy: 'ID'">

        <div ng-repeat="aut in value">

            <div class="item item-avatar bar bar-calm">

              <!-- you don't have properties name or model in your json -->
                <h2>{{aut.name}} {{aut.model}}</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="../www/img/icon/{{aut.doc_name}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that was the exact answer

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a conceptual error in your JSON (apart the one noticed by @A.Alger).
I like the *uniqueness* of an ID. For instance, in a simple database table your ID (primary key) is showed exactly one time for each `select`. If you make some join operations that ID can be present more than one time. This is fine, since database table (and `select`) lack the expressivity that JSON indeed have, so I will return a json like this:

```
[{
  "ID": "149",
  "IDusr": "4",
  "aut_more_info": "good",
  "docs": [{
    "doc_name": "img1838142879.jpeg",
    "doc_type": "jpg"
  }, {
    "doc_name": "img5733250433.jpeg",
    "doc_type": "jpg"
  }, {
    "doc_name": "img1230306801.jpg",
    "doc_type": "jpg"
  }]
}]
```

In this way the documents are naturally grouped together, and you can use your angular without any plugin:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    ID: {{user.ID}} - IDusr: {{user.IDusr}}
    <h5>Images</h5>
    <div ng-repeat="doc in user.docs">
      {{doc.doc_name}} <br>
      {{doc.doc_type}}
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpsDCkPa6ieIxWg8XzOv?p=preview) that show how it works.